# Python-Pandas: drop row if sum of multiple columns is zero

Tags: python, pandas

I have 4 float columns in my dataframe:

| Premium | Comission | RVNE | Incurred |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0.0000 | 0.0000 | 0.0000 | 0.0017 |
| 5.0000 | 3.0000 | 0.0000 | 1.0000 |
| 0.0000 | 0.0000 | 5.0000 | 2.0000 |
| 1.0000 | 3.0000 | 0.0000 | 0.0000 |

I want to round each column to 2 decimal places drop the rows in which the sum of all 4 columns is zero. In this example, only the first row should be dropped.

What is the best and most efficient approach to achieve this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You seem to be asking for someone to write some code for you. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site, not a code-writing service. Please see [Ask] to learn how to write effective questions.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of dropping the rows that sum to zero, keep the rows that sum to anything other than 0:

```
df = df.loc[df.round(2).sum(axis=1).ne(0)]
```